# Unit tests failing with Observable.FromAsync and Observable.Switch

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive

I'm having troubles testing a class that makes use of `Observable.FromAsync<T>()` and `Observable.Switch<T>()`. What it does is to wait for a trigger observable to produce a value, then it starts an async operation, and finally recollects all operations' results in a single output sequence. The gist of it is something like:

```cs
var outputStream = triggerStream
  .Select(_ => Observable
    .FromAsync(token => taskProducer.DoSomethingAsync(token)))
  .Switch();
```

I put up some sanity check tests with the bare minimum parts to understand what's going on, here's the test with results in comments:

```cs
class test_with_rx : nspec
{
  void Given_async_task_and_switch()
  {
    Subject<Unit> triggerStream = null;
    TaskCompletionSource<long> taskDriver = null;
    ITestableObserver<long> testObserver = null;
    IDisposable subscription = null;

    before = () =>
    {
      TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();
      testObserver = scheduler.CreateObserver<long>();
      triggerStream = new Subject<Unit>();
      taskDriver = new TaskCompletionSource<long>();

      // build stream under test
      IObservable<long> streamUnderTest = triggerStream
        .Select(_ => Observable
          .FromAsync(token => taskDriver.Task))
        .Switch();

      /* Also tried with this Switch() overload
      IObservable<long> streamUnderTest = triggerStream
          .Select(_ => taskDriver.Task)
          .Switch(); */

      subscription = streamUnderTest.Subscribe(testObserver);
    };

    context["Before trigger"] = () =>
    {
      it["Should not notify"] = () => testObserver.Messages.Count.Should().Be(0);
      // PASSED
    };

    context["After trigger"] = () =>
    {
      before = () => triggerStream.OnNext(Unit.Default);

      context["When task completes"] = () =>
      {
        long result = -1;

        before = () =>
        {
          taskDriver.SetResult(result);
          //taskDriver.Task.Wait();  // tried with this too
        };

        it["Should notify once"] = () => testObserver.Messages.Count.Should().Be(1);
        // FAILED: expected 1, actual 0

        it["Should notify task result"] = () => testObserver.Messages[0].Value.Value.Should().Be(result);
        // FAILED: of course, index out of bound
      };
    };

    after = () =>
    {
      taskDriver.TrySetCanceled();
      taskDriver.Task.Dispose();
      subscription.Dispose();
    };
  }
}
```

In other tests I've done with mocks too, I can see that the Func passed to FromAsync is actually invoked (e.g. `taskProducer.DoSomethingAsync(token)`), but then it looks like nothing more follows, and the output stream doesn't produce the value.

I also tried inserting some `Task.Delay(x).Wait()`, or some `taskDriver.Task.Wait()` before hitting expectations, but with no luck.

I read [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017804/unit-testing-with-fromasyncpattern) and I'm aware of schedulers, but at a first look I thought I didn't need them, no `ObserveOn()` is being used. Was I wrong? What am I missing? TA

Just for completeness, testing framework is NSpec, assertion library is FluentAssertions.

Comment: Reading Paul Betts answers (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3210009/540776)), maybe during test `FromAsync` or `Switch()` under the hood make use of that same idle scheduler/dispatcher provided by MSTest.exe ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're hitting is a case of testing Rx and TPL together.
An exhaustive explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183473/executing-tpl-code-in-a-reactive-pipeline-and-controlling-execution-via-test-sch) but I'll try to give advice for your particular code.

Basically your code is working fine, but your test is not.
`Observable.FromAsync` will transform into a `ContinueWith` on the provided task, which will be executed on the taskpool, hence asynchronously.

Many ways to *fix* your test: (from ugly to complex)

1. Sleep after result set (note wait doesn't work because Wait doesn't wait for continuations)

   ```
   taskDriver.SetResult(result);
   Thread.Sleep(50);
   ```
2. Set the result before executing `FromAsync` (because FromAsync will return an immediate IObservable if the task is finished, aka will skip `ContinueWith`)

   ```
   taskDriver.SetResult(result);
   triggerStream.OnNext(Unit.Default);
   ```
3. Replace FromAsync by a testable alternative, e.g

   ```
   public static IObservable<T> ToObservable<T>(Task<T> task, TaskScheduler scheduler)
   {
       if (task.IsCompleted)
       {
           return task.ToObservable();
       }
       else
       {
           AsyncSubject<T> asyncSubject = new AsyncSubject<T>();
           task.ContinueWith(t => task.ToObservable().Subscribe(asyncSubject), scheduler);
           return asyncSubject.AsObservable<T>();
       }
   }
   ```

(using either a [synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14458742/615903) TaskScheduler, or a [testable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853037/615903) one)

Comment: Thanks for answering. A first try with option #2 works. I used that by chance in other test cases, didn't thought it was so *crucial*. In other cases where things were not working in the past, I went with *Thread.Sleep()*, but that felt a little bad. Isn't there any overload already available in Rx for *FromAsync()* or *ToObservable()* taking an IScheduler input arg?

Comment: E.g. something like [this from Rx Githuib](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/a13e3ff05bdded5cef2bf40bface22f8fa4ae316/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Async.cs#L858)

Comment: Nice finding, didn't know it was added [recently](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/commit/627539549cbf916c0d5b65bea40792affe62143d) ! Should be in 2.3.0 betas I guess.

Comment: yes, there's a relatively old [issue](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/21) about that, mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28236216/540776) by James World